# How to make a timer in C?

Tags: c, linux

I was working on a timer in C with the `stdlib.h` header file and the `time.h` header. I was caught in an error. I would be glad if you could help me. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int s;
    int m = 0;
    while (s<=60)
    {
        system("clear");
        printf("%d Minutes %d Seconds", m, s);
        sleep(1000);
        s+=1;
        if (s==60)
        {
            m+=1;
            s=0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program is not displaying any output instead of showing a blank screen.

Comment: Well, to start with, you should initialise 's'.

Comment: `sleep()` sleeps the number of **seconds** passed into. UNIX `sleep()` is different from Windows `Sleep()`.

Comment: Also `stdout` (where `printf()` prints to) is line buffered. Suffix the strig you print with  a `\n` and the line is flushed. Alternatively you can call `fflush(stdout)` just after the `printf()`.

Comment: Help for the libc functions can be found when doing for example `man 3 sleep` on the UNIX console.

Comment: I changed it from sleep(1000) to sleep(1).Its still not working.

Comment: What would you expect the program to do, though? You did not yet tell us this.

Comment: Well by correcting all the mistakes you guys had given it is working like a charm.Thanks to all.I pretty happy that I am a part of this community.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the output of the stdout is `line-buffered`, so that if you need it update the output inside a line (before printing `\n`), you need to flush the buffer with `fflush()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int s = 0;  // init it
    int m = 0;
    while (s <= 60)
    {
        system("clear");
        printf("\r");  // move cursor to position 0
        printf("%d Minutes %d Seconds", m, s);
        fflush(stdout);  // flush the output of stdout
        sleep(1);  // in seconds
        s += 1;
        if (s==60)
        {
            m+=1;
            s=0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be wise to emphasize the flush in the solution.  That is, explicitly mention it before the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I found that the system call from my program to my pc was really slow.Any way it is a 9 year old AMD Sempron.

Comment: added some explanation :P

Comment: "*was really slow*" haha @theunixdisaster An AMD Sempron "*ought to be enough*" for such basic exercises. Have fun! :-)

Answer (score 1):

`sleep(1000)` is going to sleep for 1,000 seconds.  You also have to initialize `s` to zero since you are reading it in the `while` loop.  `sleep` is defined in *unistd.h* so you should include that as well.

Comment: Thanks about the sleep(1000) thing.I read some where that it is 1,000 ms.Thanks a lot.Thanks about making me aware of that.

Comment: <strike>I also do not completely understand why you are bothering to track the number of minutes.  The loop will stop after 1 minute so `m` will be incremented to one and then the loop exits.</strike>

Comment: "*... and then the loop exits.*" Does it?

Comment: doh ... nvm ... I didn't see the reset to zero.  Thx @alk

Comment: @theunixdisaster - make sure to add `#include <unistd.h>` as well since that is the only way to guarantee that you get the prototype for `sleep`